# trying to add dropdownList beside template field

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to implement drop down beside Template field header text like "Diameter(ddlvalues)".Drop down list will be loaded with values on page load.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvCWeight" runat="server" DataKeyNames="TPD_rowno" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="gvCWeight_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="gvCWeight_RowDataBound">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Row No">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCWeightrowno" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TPD_rowno") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Diameter"> 
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCWtProp" runat="server" Style="border: 0px;"></asp:DropDownList>                                   
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCWeightDiaMin" runat="server" Rows="1" MaxLength="10" Text='<%# Eval("diaCWeightMin") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtCWeightsizeMin_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCWeightAddRow" runat="server" OnClick="btnCWeightAddRow_Click" Text="Add Row" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am trying to add dropdownList beside template field  but showing error.Element dropdownlist is not a known element.this can occur if there is a compilation error in the website.Any idea would be appreciated how  to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                   ....................
              </ItemTemplate>
              <HeaderTemplate>
                    Full Name
             </HeaderTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
```

You can use this if you want dropdown in HeaderTemplate.